# How can I move files to a different directory and into corresponding folders by matching the file name to the folder name?

Tags: python, pdf, shutil

I have files I would like to move to different folders based on their file name.
examples of the file names are:

> 296_A_H_1_1_20070405.pdf
>
> 296_A_H_10_1_20070405.pdf
>
> 296_A_H_2_1_20070405.pdf
>
> 296_A_H_20_1_20070405.pdf

The corresponding folder names are:

> 296_A_H_1
>
> 296_A_H_2
>
> 296_A_H_10
>
> 296_A_H_20

I want to move the files to the correct folder based on the file name. For example, **296_A_H_1**_1_20070405.pdf should go in the **296_A_H_1** folder. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import shutil
import os

#filepath to files
source = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test folder'

#filepath to destination folders
dest1 = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\move file\\296_A_H_1'
dest2 = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\move file\\296_A_H_2'
dest3 = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\move file\\296_A_H_10'
dest4 = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\move file\\296_A_H_20'

files = [os.path.join(source, f) for f in os.listdir(source)]

#move files to destination folders based on file path and name
for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test folder\\296_A_H_1_")):
        shutil.copy(f,dest1)
    elif (f.startswith("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test folder\\296_A_H_2_")):
        shutil.copy(f,dest2)
    elif (f.startswith("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test folder\\296_A_H_10")):
        shutil.copy(f, dest3)
    elif (f.startswith("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test folder\\296_A_H_20")):
        shutil.copy(f, dest4)
```

This code works but I need to move 400 files to different folders and would have to write hundreds of elif statements. How can I do this by matching the file name to the destination folder and using shutil to copy the file to that folder? I am just starting to learn Python so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You basically map destinations to the files that should go to those destinations using string membership testing (i.e. `if d in x`). This of course assumes that all of the files to be moved start in the `source` folder and all of the destinations are in the same folder (`'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\move file'`).

```
source = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test folder'

dests = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\move file')

# Map each destination to the files that should go to that destination
dest_file_mapping = {d: {os.path.join(source, x
                      for x in os.listdir(source) if d in x} for d in dests}

for dest, files in dest_file_mapping.items():
    for f in files:
        shutil.copy(f, dest)
```

Comment: when I use this method I get a permission error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\Target test\\296_A_H_1'

Comment: That is because you are accessing a file that takes administrative privileges to open/edit/modify. When you open command prompt to run you python script, consider right clicking, and selecting "Run as Administrator"